# PyQt6: app shows permanetly Gnome taskbar

Tags: python, pyqt6

Running a simple PyQt6 app Gnome desktop environment shows the taskbar permanently:

[image]

OS information:

```
Distributor ID: Kali 

Description: Kali GNU/Linux

Rolling Release: 2021.3

Codename: kali-rolling
```

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 200)
    w.move(300, 300)

    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can this behaviour be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed this is normal behaviour on any application when the window is not maximized. When I maximize, the taskbar disappears.